# QT: run independent thread from other thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

Let me just give you an example.

```
class B : public  QThread {
public:
  void run() {
  }
};

class A : public QThread {
public:
  void run() {
     b1.start(); b2.start();
  }
protected:
  B b1, b2;
};
```

I want A::b1 and A::b2 to run as completely independent threads, not sharing resources of parent thread (A). Is there any way to specify main thread as parent thread of b1 and b2?

I've also looked at QThreadPool and QRunnable, and i don't understand, how is it possible to manage all runnables (for example, stop one of them, and then run it again) of threadpool.

Comment: I don't think I have the solution for this particular technology, but in most technologies a thread can be specified as daemon, in which case it gets killed when the parent is killed. Hope that's a start for you to look at...

Comment: It looks like i just did a stupid mistake: i called run() instead of start(). Now it seems OK, CPU is fully loaded :)

Answer (score 5):

Subclassing `QThread` is the [**wrong way**](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) of creating threads in Qt. `QObject` provides the function [`moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html#moveToThread) which simply allows you to change the thread affinity of an object and its children.

> Changes the thread affinity for this object and its children. The
>   object cannot be moved if it has a parent. Event processing will
>   continue in the targetThread.
>
> To move an object to the main thread, use QApplication::instance() to
>   retrieve a pointer to the current application, and then use
>   QApplication::thread() to retrieve the thread in which the application
>   lives.

So what you should do is to is to inherit from `QObject` instead of `QThread` and change your run function to move the B objects to other threads.

Sample Code (untested)

```
class B : public  QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  void run() {
  }
};

class A : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  void run() {
     b1Thread = new QThread;
     b2Thread = new QThread;
     b1.moveToThread(b1Thread);
     b2.moveToThread(b2Thread);

     b1.run(); 
     b2.run();
  }
protected:
  B b1, b2;
private:
  QThread* b1Thread, b2Thread; // Delete them in the destructor.
};
```

You could construct the threads in `main.cpp` and pass them to the `B` class as arguments.

Notice the following concerning `moveToThread`

> **this function can only "push" an object from the current thread to
>   another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread
>   to the current thread.**

Comment: http://pastie.org/2843445 <br/> When i push button - interface just freezes. Something seems to be wrong. <br/> And http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html#start says <br/> "void QThread::start ( Priority priority = InheritPriority ) [slot]

Begins execution of the thread by calling run(), which should be reimplemented in a QThread subclass to contain your code. The operating system will schedule the thread according to the priority parameter. If the thread is already running, this function does nothing.". <br/> Why is subclassing QThread wrong?

Comment: wtf is with comments on SO? lack of line breaks is really stupid

Comment: already. Meanwhile, official QT documentation says, that it's OK to subclass QThread. You also can't make the thread sleep from outside: QThread::sleep() is protected